How do I prevent hydration errors when another website uses my Next.js page as a wrapper?
I am creating a website for a realty client using a (new to me) service called IDX Broker. The way their service works is by taking a page from my site (for example, example.com/listings) and uses it as a wrapper for their page by looking through the DOM on my site and finding two div tags. In this case, their page is just a set of inputs for a building address to search for.
<div id="idxStart"></div>
<div id="idxStop"></div>

It seemingly loads their page and then loads the wrapper around it. So when I go to their page I can see their page (the search input boxes and buttons) load but then the wrapper loads and their page disappears.
The expected behavior is that the user can go to the IDX site and see the IDX page (the search page) with my page from my site wrapped around it effectively replacing the divs mentioned above with the HTML from the IDX page.
Currently the page acting as the wrapper is just a simple header and footer. The IDX site is also using a CNAME to change it from the IDX Broker site to listings.example.com. I don't think the issue is related to that, but it might be relevant so I'm including it.
I have tried changing how the site loads using useEffect, but I might be using it incorrectly.
Here are some of the errors from the console on the current page:
69-9ea0f23f80313f55.js:1 Failed to fetch RSC payload for https://listings.example.com/. Falling back to browser navigation. TypeError: Failed to fetch

Access to fetch at 'https://example.com/' (redirected from 'https://listings.example.com/?_rsc=1ws4l') from origin 'https://listings.example.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

Uncaught Error: Minified React error #418; visit https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=418 for the full message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and additional helpful warnings.

Uncaught Error: Minified React error #423; visit https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=423 for the full message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and additional helpful warnings.


I solved it. After testing out some of the no SSR options in React, I settled on using dangerouslySetInnerHTML.
If anyone has a suggestion that doesn’t involve using that property, I would happily implement it.
